# How to give alpha value for WKWebView in swift?

Tags: swift, background-color, wkwebview, alpha

I am Using `WKWebView` to show `webpage`, here i want to add `alpha` value to `webpage` while open the side menu. I am able to add `alpha` value to `UIView` but which is not working for `WKWebView`? How to add `alpha` value to `WKWebView` and delete that value?

For view i am using and works:

```
      view?.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.7)
```

For `WKWebView` it's not working why?

```
     aboutusWeb.isOpaque = false
     testWebView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.7)
```

Complete  code for `webview`:

```
 import UIKit
 import WebKit
 import SideMenu
 class AboutUsController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

  @IBOutlet weak var aboutusWeb: WKWebView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      guard let url = URL(string: "https://developer.apple.com/swift/") else { return }
      let request = URLRequest(url: url)

      aboutusWeb.load(request)

  }
  @IBAction func sideMenubtn(_ sender: Any) {
      print("in aboutus")

    aboutusWeb.isOpaque = false
    aboutusWeb?.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.9)
  }
 }
  extension AboutUsController : UISideMenuNavigationControllerDelegate {
  internal func sideMenuWillDisappear(menu: UISideMenuNavigationController, animated: Bool) {
  //*do the color thing*
      print("sidemenu disappear")
  aboutusWeb?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
 }
 }
```

Please help me to add alpha value to `WKWebView` and delete that value.

Answer (score 0):

not sure about alpha but can set Transparent background for WKWebView with this code

```
webView.opaque = false
webView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
webView.scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

Comment: added your updated code in my wkwebview controller `viewWillAppear` and tried in viewDidLoad but not working...  have you tried??

Comment: where should i use this code.. i tried in viewWillAppear and viewDidLoad.. nothing worked.. please suggest something

Comment: try to add code in             DispatchQueue.main.async {   }